# Jenkins and Subversion plugin with multiple modules - Avoid deletion

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins v1.558 and Subversion plugin v2.4.

In "Source Code Management" configuration page, I choose "Subversion Modules" and add 2 of them:

`- http://11.22.33.44/svn/repository/folderOne
- http://11.22.33.44/svn/repository/folderTwo`

`Check-out Strategy: Use 'svn update' as much as possible`

These 2 folders contain source code:

```
- folderOne: source1.c
- folderOne: source2.c
```

When I launch the Job, I can see in the log file that:

1. Contents of `folderOne` are well downloaded in the workspace I have indicated
2. Contents of `folderOne` are **deleted**
3. Contents of `folderTwo` are well downloaded in the workspace I have indicated

---

**Edit**:
At the end, I expect to have *only* the contents of these 2 folders in my workspace, not the folders. 
Expected:

```
 - workspace 
    + source1.c
    + source2.c
```

Not expected:

```
 - workspace
      + folderOne
          * source1.c
      + folderTwo
          * source2.c
```

Current situation:

```
 - workspace
     + source2.c
```

---

So, do you know if there is a way to avoid this deletion, to tell to Jenkins/Subversion plugin to keep all the files?

Comment: Why wouldn't you check out the whole repository?  It seems you may want to revisit the layout of the repo?

Comment: Yes, I have to checkout this way for structural reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set a subdirectory for the checkouts. You can do this per folder in the svn settings, the "Local module directory" field for each.

Comment: In fact, I'd like _only_ the contents of these folders to be checked out in the workspace, not the folders. I'll edit my post.

Comment: svn will still not let you checkout the contents of a folder into a folder that contains files. Try it with the command line and you'll see it deletes the contents first. You can checkout just children with a --depth option, but it won't help here. Checkout to 2 folders, and then xcopy them into a common location as an initial build step if necessary.

Comment: Ok, that's why. Checking out and then copying sounds good ! Thanks :)